# Having difficulty getting numbers to display in grid cells

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am attempting to make an interactive sudoku solver, I've managed to make a grid of different elements that represents an empty sudoku grid. However when I try to actually have any numbers display in the grid cells, I come up short.
https://jsfiddle.net/retsek860/w98fr42v/

```
function createGrid() {
    for (var rows = 0; rows < 9; rows++) {
        for (var columns = 0; columns < 9; columns++) {
            cell = "<div class='grid' "
            if (rows%3==2) {
                cell += "style='box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, "
            } else {
                cell += "style='box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(150, 150, 150), "
            }
            if (rows%3==0) {
                cell += "0 -1px 0 #000, "
            } else {
                cell += "0 -1px 0 rgb(150, 150, 150), "
            }
            if (columns%3==2) {
                cell += "1px 0 0 #000, "
            } else {
                cell += "1px 0 0 rgb(150, 150, 150), "
            }
            if (columns%3==0) {
                cell += "-1px 0 0 #000;'>4</div>"
            } else {
                cell += "-1px 0 0 rgb(150, 150, 150);'>3</div>"
            }
            $("#container").append(cell);
        }
    }
    $(".grid").width(90);
    $(".grid").height(90);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    createGrid()
});
```

As you can see each one of those cells actually has either a 3 or 4 in it, but you can't see any of them :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`font-size` is set to 0:

[image: font_size_0px screenshot]

After setting `font-size: 14px;`:

[image: screenshot after setting font-size]